# Manipulate style elements of a Button via jquery: depending on the state of another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, accordion

Another question from me. I am actually writing a little HTML/CSS3/jQuery project with the intention to learn more :-).

I could solve all problems by my own except one, that gives my a bad headache now.

Here is it: I want to set a style via jQuery for a button element. On page load set it to `display:none`.

```
<div class="header">
    <img id="button" src="img/back_button.jpg"/>
</div>
```

with the css;

```
#button{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  float:left;
  display: none;
}
```

The button's function is to collapse all accordion I use on click.

```
$('#button').bind('click',function(){
        $('.accord').collapsible("option","collapsed", true );
    });
```

So I need to ask for the state of the accordion/collapsible and set the style.display to block, when a accordion is active. Only if the accordion is open i want to see the button. I tried several things like;

```
var status = $('[data-role=collapsible]).hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')
if(status){
        $('#button').css("display", "block")
    }
    else{console.log("foo")}
```

or

```
$("[data-role=collapsible]").on('collapse', $.proxy(function () {
            $('#button').css("display", "block")
        }, this)).on('expand', $.proxy(function () {
            $('#button').css("display", "none")
        }, this));
```

or

```
if($('.accord').collapsible("option","collapsed", true )){
        $('#button').show();
    }
    else if($('.accord').collapsible("option","expand", true )){
        $('#button').hide();
}
```

but somehow I can't get the result I want. Can you guys (& girls) help me out please?

Comment: Can you post your relevant HTML, and perhaps *also* (*not* instead of) post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to work with? And, incidentally, you don't have a 'button element,' you have an `img` element, with the *`id`* of 'button'.

Comment: i think its not working properly in the fiddle, but you can review the code there. http://jsfiddle.net/ZKMp6/

Comment: listen to `collapsiblecollapse` and `collapsibeexpand` events to hide/show button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `collapsiblecollapse` and `collapsibleexpand` events, check if any collapsibles are currently open ( `$("[data-role=collapsible]").not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed").length > 0` ) and show or hide the button based on this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#btnCollapse").hide();

    $("#btnCollapse").on("click", function() {
        $('[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible("option","collapsed", true );
    });

    $('[data-role=collapsible]').on("collapsiblecollapse collapsibleexpand", function(){
        if ( $("[data-role=collapsible]").not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed").length > 0){
            $("#btnCollapse").show();   
        } else {
            $("#btnCollapse").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rjMj7/)**

Comment: hi ezanker. this works pretty well for me. also i now understood my mistakes. thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

it now works with this js

```
define(['jquery', 'jqueryMobile'], function($) {

    if($('.accord').collapsible("option","collapsed", true )){
    $('#button').hide();
}

$('[data-role=collapsible]').on("collapsiblecollapse collapsibleexpand", function(){
        if ( $("[data-role=collapsible]").not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed").length > 0){
            $("#button").show();
            $('#button').bind('click',function(){
                $('.accord').collapsible("option","collapsed", true );
            });
        } else {
            $("#button").hide();
        }
    });
});
```